# Reopen STDOUT and STDERR after closing them?

Tags: bash

In bash consider I did this stupid thing:

```
$ exec 1>&-
$ exec 2>&-
```

I am sure I have not yet lost the game (oops actually I lost [The Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Game_(mind_game))) and I can reconnect to stdout. The think is I don't know how.

First thing I tried is create a fifo and using another shell to monitor stdout of the first shell. It did not work, I don't know why:

#### tty1

```
$ mkfifo stdout
$ exec 1>stdout
$ echo "Hello stdout"
```

#### tty2

```
$ tail -f stdout
$ # nothing here
```

> How can I reconnect my closed `STDOUT` and `STDERR` after all?

I know that a solution would be to save STDOUT before playing with it:

```
$ exec 3>&1
$ exec 1>&-
$ echo "Nothing will see this"
$ exec 1<&3 # Restoring stdout
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am running this on an Ubuntu machine, so I am not sure if it'll work for you, but this is what I did:

```
$ exec 1>&0
$ exec 2>&0
```

Suddenly, I had STDOUT and STDERR reconnected. Magic!

**Explanation:** Running the following commands, we get the following output:

```
$ ls -l /dev/stdout
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jun 11 23:39 /dev/stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1

$ ls -l /proc/self/fd/1
lrwx------ 1 jay jay 64 Jun 22 01:34 /proc/self/fd/1 -> /dev/pts/10

$ ls -l /proc/self/fd/
total 0
lrwx------ 1 jay jay 64 Jun 22 01:35 0 -> /dev/pts/10
lrwx------ 1 jay jay 64 Jun 22 01:35 1 -> /dev/pts/10
lrwx------ 1 jay jay 64 Jun 22 01:35 2 -> /dev/pts/10
lr-x------ 1 jay jay 64 Jun 22 01:35 3 -> /proc/12224/fd
```

Since all three fd's point to the same thing, we can return them back to normal just by pointing to /dev/pts/10 which the `exec 1>&0` and `exec 2>&0` do

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way, since you haven't closed `stdin`, which is also connected to your terminal:

```
exec 2>&0 1>&0
```

You could also use `/dev/tty`:

```
exec 2>/dev/tty 1>&2
```

You have to do that blind, since `stderr` is where `bash` echos what you type, and without `stderr`, it can't echo.

Comment: Well, I think I got the trick. &0, &1 and &2 are both the same file pointer, my current terminal right?