# Disable .zshenv output for non-interactive shell

Tags: shell, zsh, non-interactive

My `.zshenv` produces some output that is only helpful when my shell is interactive.
In other cases when the shell is not interactive this output (i.e. when I run script) must be hidden.

How can I suppress `.zshenv` output for non-interactive shell?

P.S. I added my current solution below but it seems hackish to me.

Comment: Put the code in `.zshrc` instead of `.zshenv` if it doesn't do anything aside from produce the output.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for advice, but actually I moved the code from `.zshrc` to `.zshenv` because it sets up environment both for interactive and non-interactive shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[My other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44656473/746347) does not work well in some cases.

I moved `.zshenv` content to a function `run` and added conditional redirection for this function output:

```
function run() {
    // .zshenv content
}

OUTPUT=1

if [[ ! -o interactive ]]; then
    OUTPUT=3
    eval "exec $OUTPUT<>/dev/null"
fi

run >& $OUTPUT

if [[ ! -o interactive ]]; then
   eval "exec $OUTPUT>&-"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I added:

```
if [[ ! -o interactive ]]; then
    exec 1>&-
    exec 1<>/dev/null
fi
```

at the top of my `.zshenv` file to close original `1` stdout file descriptor and assign `/dev/null` to it.

And at the bottom I added:

```
if [[ ! -o interactive ]]; then
  exec 1>&0
fi
```

to restore it (see [Reopen STDOUT and STDERR after closing them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30968734/746347)).